# How to give an imageView in swift3.0.1 shadow at the same time with rounded corners

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to give an imageView a shadow at the same time with rounded corners,but I failed.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution

**Basic idea :**

1. Use an Extra view (say AView) as super view of image view (to those views on which you are willing to have shado) and assign that view class to **DGShadoView**
2. Pin Image view to **AView** (that super view)from left, right, top and bottom with constant 5
3. Set back ground color of the **AView** to *clear color*  **from storybosrd's Property inspector this is important**

**Inside idea:** *Here we are using a Bezier path on the Aview nearly on border and setting all rounded corner properties and shadow properties to that path and we are placing our target image view lie with in that path bound*

```
@IBDesignable
class DGShadoView:UIView {

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    self.rect = rect
    decorate(rect: self.rect)
}

func decorate(rect:CGRect) {


    //self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear 
    //IMPORTANT: dont forgot to set bg color of your view to clear color from story board's property inspector 

    let ref = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let contentRect = rect.insetBy(dx: 5, dy: 5);
    /*create the rounded oath and fill it*/
    let roundedPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: contentRect, cornerRadius: 5)
    ref!.setFillColor("your color for background".cgColor)
    ref!.setShadow(offset: CGSize(width:0,height:0), blur: 5, color: "your color for shado".cgColor)
    roundedPath.fill()

    /*draw a subtle white line at the top of view*/
    roundedPath.addClip()
    ref!.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    ref!.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.overlay)
    ref!.move(to: CGPoint(x:contentRect.minX,y:contentRect.minY+0.5))
    ref!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:contentRect.maxX,y:contentRect.minY+0.5))
}
```

}

**Update**

**Extension Approach**

There is another Approach. Just Make a class with empty and paste Following UIImageView Extension code, Assign this subclass to that ImageView on which you shadow.

```
import UIKit

class DGShadowView: UIImageView {

    @IBInspectable var intensity:Float = 0.2{
        didSet{
           setShadow()
        }
    }
    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setShadow()
    }

    func setShadow(){
        let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds)
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.3)
        layer.shadowOpacity = intensity
        layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create two separate views. One for the shadow and one for the image itself. On the imageView you clipToBounds the layer so that the corner radius is properly added.

Put the imageView on top of the shadowView and you've got your solution!